# Creating an index for YEAR() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to accelerate a query. This query looks if the year is '2017'. I'm comparing costing between using: `LIKE = '2017%'`, `YEAR (date) = '2017'` and  `date BETWEEN '2017-1-1' AND '2017-12-31'`.

I would like to make an index for the colum date but using the function year,  something similar to:

```
CREATE INDEX indexDATE ON
table (YEAR(date));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you may want to create a materialized view

Comment: Yes, I know, but, If possible, I would like to create an index. If there is no more choice I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to express the logic is:

```
date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

or as I prefer:

```
date >= '2017-01-01' AND date < '2018-01-01'
```

This can use an index on `(date)`.

The expression `LIKE = '2017%'` is simply bad coding.  You are using string functions on a date/time column.  That is a really bad idea and it precludes the use of indexes.

The expression `YEAR (date) = 2017` is logically ok -- once you remove the single quotes around the number.  However, the use of the function on the column precludes the use of an index.

Finally, in most data sets, years are not very selective.  That is, you are still going to be selecting a significant portion of the rows.  Indexes are less useful for such queries.